# Fastest way to get data from cursor in Android

Tags: android, cursor

I have a query & it will return only one item. I can get the result like this

```
cursorOne.moveToFirst();
    do 
    {
        getID = cursorOne.getString(cursorOne.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
    }while (cursorOne.moveToNext());
```

I want know is there any fastest way to get the data or this is the only way.

Comment: you do not need loop for this, use: `if(cursorOne.moveToFirst()) { getID = cursorOne.getString(cursorOne.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")); }` but if query really returns only one row there should be no differences

Answer (score 0):

Use a projection when querying so you only return the column you require

```
String[] projection = new String[] { "_id" }; //specify columns you want to return
Cursor cursorOne = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

There's no need for a do/while when getting your results if it's only returning a single row.

```
try {
  if (cursorOne.moveToFirst()) { 
     getID = cursorOne.getString(0); //no need to look up column index since you already know it due to the projection used
  }
} finally {
  cursorOne.close();
}
```

Comment: you still have to loop through each row if you need multiple rows which is what he is trying to avoid i believe

Comment: Oh, I thought he was only interested in a single row. I'll delete this if he confirms that.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a single column value from a single row, consider using an [`SQLiteStatement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) instead of a cursor. SQLiteStatement supports `simpleQueryForLong()` and `simpleQueryForString()` which each return a single value.